# What is meaning of "How do you do that" here and "I'm pushing my Aunt Roz through Parrot Jungle"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Frannie: Hey, Monica!

Monica: Hey Frannie, welcome back! How was Florida?

Frannie: You had sex, didn't you?

Monica: **how do you do that?**

Frannie: Oh, I hate you, **I'm pushing my Aunt Roz through Parrot Jungle** and you're having sex!  So? Who?

Answer (score 3):

By **"How do you do that?"** Monica basically means *"How do you know?"* or "*How can you tell?"* It's an indication that Frannie has guessed correctly, and frequently guesses correctly.

[**Parrot Jungle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jungle_Island) is the old name of an animal theme park in Florida.

Frannie's line is a complaint: that while she has been accompanying her (possibly elderly) aunt to the theme park--likely literally pushing her in a wheel chair, but perhaps just in a generally assistive capacity--Monica has been having fun.